# Como alinhar o carousel com o jumbotron?

Tags: carousel

```html
    <div class="jumbotron text-center ">
        <h1>Titulo</h1>
        <p>Subtitulo</p>
    
    </div>
    <!-- end top -->

  <div id="carousel-example-generic"  class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Texto 1 blah blah blah</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Texto 2 blah blah blah</h1>
            </div>
          </div> 
          <div class="item">
            <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Texto 3 blah blah blah</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          ...
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Por favor, informe se tem algum css além do que foi mostrado, js também...

Comment: É Bootstrap 3 ou 4?Edite a sua pergunta e coloca uma imagem de como está ficando na sua tela.

Comment: Boa tarde, é o 3.3.7, estou fazendo um curso e seguindo os parametros por isso usei esse, porém parei nessa situação, o CSS e JS é o proprio do bootstrap.

Comment: Mas o que vc quer dizer com "alinhar" eles estão desalinhados? O que está errado no layout, seja mais específico

Comment: Bom dia,
desculpe a expressão então eu gostaria de poder deixar os dois elementos grudados, pois tenho um nav, abaixo um jumbotron e a baixo um carousel. O nav esta em primeiro ao topo, apenas atribui a classe a ele navbar-fixed-top e tirou o espaçamento entre o nav e a div jumbotron.